# psql table querying

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I have 3 tables, players, matches, wins. I want to make a query that retrieves back the player id, the name, the amount of matches he played and how many wins he got.

the matches table keeps track of the round it's in, the players who take part (p_one_id and p_two_id) while the wins table keeps track of the match id, to see who he won against, and the player id.

if I do

```
SELECT players.id, players.name, COUNT(matches.*) as matches FROM players, matches WERE matches.p_one_id = players.id GROUP BY players.id
```

It works fine, at least from my basic tests ( but that doesn t also check for wins) but if I do

```
SELECT players.id, players.name, COUNT(matches.*) as matches, COUNT(wins.*) AS wins FROM players, matches, wins WERE matches.p_one_id = players.id AND wins.p_id = players.id GROUP BY players.id
```

I get nothing, one reason is that there's no wins, but then I d only get the guys who won, I can t make a sub query either, since I can't use the player id inside of the subquery, at least not from my knowledge). Anyone know what query I'd need for my result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a LEFT JOIN instead of the cross join / where clause option.  You may also wish to count the matches where the player was "player 2".  Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    count(m1.*) + count(m2.*) as matches,
    count(w.*) as wins
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN matches m1
ON m.p_one_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN matches m2
on m.p_two_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN wins w
ON w.p_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Comment: thanks a lot, especially for the match in case the player was nr 2, works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

User outer joins.  The join syntax you're using is eliminating players unless they have both wins and matches.

```
SELECT players.id, players.name, 
       COUNT(matches.p_one_id) as matches, 
       COUNT(wins.p_id) AS wins 
FROM players
LEFT JOIN matches
 on matches.p_one_id = players.id 
LEFT JOIN wins 
 on wins.p_id = players.id 
GROUP BY players.i, players.name
```

This will return all players, matches, and wins.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, not sure which one of you guys said it first, but both work perfectly